# Localizing games for various countries

Tags: iphone, localization, app-store

I am developing an iPhone game and want to sell it in different regions, making it available in a number of languages.

Should the app be repackaged in each different version for each language, (e.g. Japanese, English, Chinese etc), or would one game package all the art and language and then detect where it is and display accordingly?

Does Apple allow mutliple versions of one game to be submitted, each game with a different language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By all means go for a single app. And if done correctly - which is very easy - the system will chose the correct language automatically. So don't use a language setting, either.

Having many different versions can easily get a pain, both to support and for the customer, who will simply be frustrated because he easily buys the wrong version.

If I were Apple (which I'm not) I'd say this is a typical case of spamming the AppStore and would ban you from there...

So do the reasonable thing -> *one* app for all.

Comment: I dont think they will ban a developer, but yeah it would become a pain.

Answer (score 0):

As Eiko said, go for one app, although I disagree that Apple would ban you.

Look at the Apple documentation for "[Internationalization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/)" for help on how to do so.